# Is there a possibility to add a project reference for python in vscode?

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

With C# projects, there is an easy way to reference other projects inside a solution. Now, I would like to know, if there is a similar way in python projects.

Lets say, I have a folder structure like this:

```
Base_directory/Project/SomeFile.py
Base_directory/Project_UnitTests/SomeFileTests.py
```

SomeFile.py

```
class SomeClass:
    pass
```

For the unit tests, it works fine, if I use relative imports. SomeFileTests.py:

```
from ..Project.SomeFile import SomeClass
#...
```

But, what I would like to achieve is to have the following code:

```
from Project.SomeFile import SomeClass
#...
```

But for this, I obviously need a reference to the Project folder. I know, I could work with the python-path variable directly inside the code, but then I would need to have the path to that folder inside the unit test code - and I do not think, it belongs there.

Is there an elegant way to add project references in Visual Studio Code using Python?

Comment: you need to add the location of the Project folder to your python PATH environment or move the folder somewhere already in your PATH

Comment: does Python use the env variable `PYTHON_PATH`, you have to set this env var before you start VSC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify PYTHONPATH through `terminal.integrated.env.*` and/or within an `.env` file. You can refer to official docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable).

> The PYTHONPATH environment variable specifies additional locations
> where the Python interpreter should look for modules. In VS Code,
> PYTHONPATH can be set through the terminal settings
> (**terminal.integrated.env.***) and/or within an **.env** file.

But they are some different:

> When the terminal settings are used, PYTHONPATH affects any tools that
> are run within the terminal by a user, as well as any action the
> extension performs for a user that is routed through the terminal such
> as debugging. However, in this case when the extension is performing
> an action that isn't routed through the terminal, such as the use of a
> linter or formatter, then this setting will not have an effect on
> module look-up.
>
> When PYTHONPATH is set using an .env file, it will affect anything the
> extension does on your behalf and actions performed by the debugger,
> but it will not affect tools run in the terminal.
>
> If needed, you can set PYTHONPATH using both methods.

Exactly meet your target:

> An example of when to use PYTHONPATH would be if you have source code
> in a src folder and tests in a tests folder. When running tests,
> however, those tests can't normally access modules in src unless you
> hard-code relative paths.
>
> To solve this problem, you could add the path to src to PYTHONPATH by
> creating an .env file within your VS Code workspace.
>
> PYTHONPATH=src
>
> Then set python.envFile in your settings.json file to
> point to the .env file you just created. For example, if the .env file
> was in your workspace root, your settings.json would be set as shown:
>
> "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"